# String.Format Argument Null Exception

Tags: c#

The below code will throw Argument Null Exception

```
var test = string.Format("{0}", null);
```

However, this will give back an empty string

```
string something  = null; 
var test = string.Format("{0}", something);
```

Just curious to know why the second piece of code doesn't throw up exception. Is this a bug ?

Comment: Interesting question! Please remember to use code-block formatting in the future, it makes the question much more readable. I went ahead and fixed it for you.

Comment: Thank You for editing. when I am about to edit you did it by the time already :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The difference is that the first piece of code is calling [`string.Format(string, object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b1csw23d.aspx)... whereas the second piece of code is calling [`string.Format(string, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fht0f5be.aspx).

`null` is a valid argument for the second method (it's just expected to be the value for the first placeholder), but not the first (where the `null` would usually be the *array* of placeholders). In particular, compare the documentation for when `NullArgumentException` is thrown:

> `string.Format(string, object)`:
>   *format* is `null`

But:

> `string.Format(string, object[])`:
>   *format* or *args* is `null`

Think of `string.Format(string, object)` as being implemented *something* like:

```
public static string Format(string format, Object arg0)
{
    return string.Format(format, new object[] { arg0 } );
}
```

So after a bit of replacement, your code is closer to:

```
// Broken code
object[] args = null; // No array at all
var test = string.Format("{0}", args); 

// Working code
object[] args = new object[] { null }; // Array with 1 value
var test = string.Format("{0}", args);
```

Comment: +1. The last code block was what finally gave me the 'ah ha!' moment.

Comment: If someone still wonders about the rules that in this case make the compiler choose `string.Format(string, params object[])` over `string.Format(string, object)` might want to read the C# specification chapter "*Better function member*" (in ECMA standard it is chapter *14.4.2.2*, in current MS standard it is chapter *7.5.3.2*) -- it boils down to that the `null` argument does not require `params object[]` to be expanded, and that `object[]` is a more specific parameter type than `object`.

Comment: @elgonzo: I don't know how well such a thing could be worked into the existing .NET now, but an amazing number of problems have resulted from the inability to "prioritize" overloads or control conversions should be associated with them.  In some cases, the notion of "specificity" makes sense, but there are many others where it yields nonsensical results.  I'm not sure one could devise better "rules", though--what's really needed is a means of letting the overloads themselves say (via attributes) what kinds of conversion should or should not be applied.

Comment: @supercat, you misunderstood something -- there is no conversion neccessary. You can assign a literal `null` value to an object array without any conversion (like `object[] arr = null;`), right? There is nothing nonsensical about it...

Comment: @elgonzo: A null literal isn't a reference of any particular type; while the passing of one as an `Object[]` is performed by passing `default(Object[])`, rather than by casting a null reference to `Object[]`, a null literal *behaves* as though it were a type unto itself which supports an implicit conversion to any reference type.

Comment: @supercat, i see what you meant. You referred to the implicit conversion mentioned in the MS spec about the `null` literal - which is written as such only in the MS standard, but not in the ECMA standard -- typical case of misunderstanding because of varying standards documents... (sigh)

Comment: @elgonzo: The expression `default(Object[])` *has a type*.  Given `public static Type GetGenericType<T>(T it) { return typeof(T); }`, the expression `GetGenericType(default(Object[]))` would yield `Object[]`.  The token `null` *has no type*.  It may be freely converted to any reference or nullable type, but calling `GetGenericType(null)` would fail because the compiler would be unable to infer any type for the null.  Note that if you used `String.Format("{0}", default(Object))`, the compiler would use the `Object` overload because the reference is of type `Object`.

Comment: @supercat, i never claimed that the `null` literal has any type. and the `null` literal obviously is not identical to `default(Object)`... i think we are somewhat lost in our discussion here  (perhaps you saw my last comment before i edited it, which i did when i got a hunch to compare MS and ECMA standard regarding your "implicit conversion" comment) :)

Comment: @elgonzo: In any case, I think my point is that while null literal is implicitly convertible to any reference type, I do not think it's helpful to consider it a "better" match for a `SiameseCat` than for an `Animal`.  In some cases, a null literal may be legitimate argument for one overload, but not another; being able to let the overloads indicate which one should be preferable given a null literal would seem better than having the compiler choose the one which is, if anything, less likely to be prepared to accept it.

Comment: @supercat, fair point. I agree with you that an overload of a method that is selected by the compiler due to a literal `null` argument value should be able to handle this gracefully - bailing out with an exception while there is another overload that could handle `null` is far from elegant nor desirable...

Comment: @elgonzo: I think we're in agreement there, but to my mind that shouldn't mean that the `Object[]` overload should accept null, but rather that the `null` should not be considered a better match for `Object[]` than `Object`.  To my mind, if an method has overloads for both `Object` and a type `T`, the latter likely expects that *the passed-in reference will identify something that may be used as a `T`*, while the former will be prepared for something it can't do anything with.

Answer (score 16):

The second code snippet is calling the following overload:

```
Format(String, Object)
```

Here the value can be null, as per the documentation.

The first code snippet uses the following overload:

```
Format(String, Object[])
```

Here the **second value *cannot* be null**, as per the documentation.

Comment: But, in the document it also tells "Thrown by all overloads". Am I missing something?

Comment: @AmitJoki, you missed the part "Condition: **format** is null." there in the documentation...

Comment: @AmitJoki It states which parameters being null results in it being thrown.

Comment: @elgonzo yeah! Got it.

Answer (score 0):

A minor point not mentioned by existing answers, and almost makes the question moot:

The full message for the `ArgumentNullException` is:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: args

Also part of the issue here is `null` is of any type. Explicitly casting it to `string` or `object` (or use the C# `default()` feature) would avoid the problem.